# Does the order of Insertion items in mysql affect the speed of insertion

Tags: mysql

I have a need to insert more than 50,000 records with 200+ fields and wondered if it was important to line up the insertion url to match the items one for one.. or will the time be insignificant.. for example.

```
    INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`id`,`fname`,`lname, `age`)
    values(Joe,Jordan,21);

    INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`id`,`age, fname`,`lname) 
    values(1,21,Joe,Jordan);


    To clarify here is the layout of the data base..
    Field 1 = fname
    Field 2 = lname
    Field 3 = age
```

So the db has the fields laid out from left to right but as you can see on the second insertion the order of fields matches the data being entered however only the top Insert matches the order of the data base from left to right.
Morale of the story the data huge amounts is laid out as the second one and the question is.. if a quick rearrangement of the data to match the order of the db would it save measuralble time or no...

Psychollogically it seems like if i line up 200 buckets and go along dropping acorns into the buckets as i come to them it would be faster.. Like i don't have to run down to bucket 155 and drop one then come back to bucket 3...LOL..

With the simple example of couse speed wont matter but there will be 50,000 acorns and 200+ buckets... If no one knows then i will set it up and test to be sure.

Comment: I dont have any reference. But I seriously doubt this would have any effect on speed. Because even when you put the fields on the same order the db engine have to check and do the mapping to the table fields. Once the map is done the insert work the same for all the rows.

Comment: Actual table order is going to be marginally faster.  ON your first example, you aren't inserting the id, which leads me to believe you have it set to auto gen.  The second you specify the id.  so that's a little confusing.  If you are only inserting 50,000 rows, I really wouldn't worry that much about optimizing for fractions of milliseconds.  Particularly if it's a one time affair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is impact on the speed if you swap fields.

It will be better to re-arrange your values to match with the original order like in the example#1 so that you can execute single query as shownbelow which is faster than that in example#2,

```
example#1
INSERT INTO wp_realty_listingsdb (`id`,`fname`,`lname`, `age`) VALUES(1,'Joe','Jordan',21),(2,'Joe','Jordan',21);

example#2
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`fname`,`lname`, `age`) values('Joe','Jordan',21);
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`id`,`age`, `fname`,`lname`)  values(1,21,'Joe','Jordan');
```

Also, it will be better to have the records imported as SQL file from MySQL console instead uploading via GUI applications.
You can use the below command to import the file from MySQL console,

```
mysql>use yourdbname;
mysql>source /path/to/sql/file.sql
```